# Add loading page until my application work in Android

Tags: android, video, loading, display

I am developing an app similar to Shazam but with video. 
My app have to process a video and in this time the display become all black. Is it possible to implement a "loading"? So while the phone elaborate the video I don't see black screen but a sort of loading page. Any suggestion? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by using a `ProgressDialog`:

```
ProgressDialog dialog=new ProgressDialog(context);
dialog.setMessage("message");
dialog.setCancelable(false);
dialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(false);
dialog.show();
```

And when you done with your process call:

```
dialog.hide();
```

Comment: I have not a variable context of type Context in that activity. How is better to declare it?

Comment: You can use `getApplicationContext()` instead.

Comment: Now I can compile but the app crash at 'dialog.show();' with this error: " Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application"